# What cause the driver dependency issue in dual boot?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, bluetooth

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Windows 10 as dual boot (of course using grub menu with default entry of ubuntu).

Since past few days I was unable to use bluetooth because it shows no bletooth adapter, during boot it shows error like below:

```
Bluetooth: hci0: don't support firmware rome 0x31010000
```

even when I executed `bluetoothctl` and tried to execute some of it's commands like `list`, `scan on` etc none of them worked no device adapter found.

To check whether bluetooth is working I ran windows and found that bluetooth was disabled from windows system option and when I enabled it and ran ubuntu again the bluetooth is working now..

So I just want to inquire what kind of dependency is this? If I disabled bluetooth driver from windows what is affecting it to not showing any bluetooth device at all in ubuntu system?

Comment: What kernel are you using? `uname -r` and edit question to include results for `lsusb` but I suspect Bluetooth device is 0cf3:3004

Comment: `4.15.0-33-generic`